# How to show in CodeIgniter only the second parameter in form validation message?

Tags: codeigniter

E.g. I have this line in my language form_validation file:

```
$lang['min_length'] = "%s must be at least %s characters in length.";
```

And I want the output to be like this:

```
$lang['min_length'] = "This field must be at least %s characters in length.";
```

However, the problem is that it looks like this when echoed:

**This field must be at least Your name characters in length.**

which is wrong because it takes the first %s instead of the second %s.

How can I force CI to take the second %s? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `min_length` is a standard function in the Form Validation Library and treated through this library, you can only do so by changing the core library.

But there is an easier way - using a callback function with the Form Validation Library:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('your_field', 'The Field label', 'callback_my_min_length[10]');
```

Then within your controller, add this:

```
public function username_check($str, $min_length)
{
    if ( mb_strlen($str) >= $min_length)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('my_min_length', 'This field must be at least '.$min_length.' characters in length.');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is how I would do it.